# React leaflet showing createRef unexpected token error in example

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I am using the react-leaflet example events.js from [github](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/example/components/events.js)
and I get the following error:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token (23:26)

  21 |   }
  22 | 
> 23 |   mapRef = createRef<Map>()
     |                           ^
  24 | 
  25 |   handleClick = () => {
  26 |     const map = this.mapRef.current
```

I changed is the import line in events.js to

```
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
```

and my App.js looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import './myLeaflet.css';
import './leaflet.css';

import SimpleExample from './simple';
import TooltipExample from './tooltip';
import DraggableExample from './draggable-marker';
import WMSTileLayerExample from './wms-tile-layer';
import EventsExample from './events';
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <EventsExample/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

myLeaflet.css contains this:

```
h1, h2, p {
  text-align: center;
}
.leaflet-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: react-leaflet uses Flow library for type checking. So either install it and use `mapRef = createRef<Map>()` or just use  `mapRef = createRef()`

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from 'react';
```

you must `import createRef` from react library and use `mapRef = createRef()`

https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/example/components/draggable-marker.js

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
 change

```
mapRef = createRef<Map>()
```

to:

```
mapRef = createRef();
```

and now it works. good luck

Answer (score 0):

ts eror with

```
mapRef = createRef();
```

changet it to

```
const mapRef = createRef<any>()
```